# Python - List of unique dictionaries where each dictionary value is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say I got a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[
 {'101': ['A','B'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['D'],
  '104': [],
  '105': [],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']},
 {'101': ['A'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['B'],
  '104': ['D'],
  '105': ['E'],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']},
{'101': ['A','B'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['D'],
  '104': [],
  '105': [],
  'deck': ['E','F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}
]
```

and I need to obtain a list of unique dictionaries (removing the duplicates):

```
[
 {'101': ['A','B'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['D'],
  '104': [],
  '105': [],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']},
 {'101': ['A'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['B'],
  '104': ['D'],
  '105': ['E'],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}
]
```

I tried

```
unique_solutions = list(set(val for dic in full_solutions_list for val in dic.values()))
```

But the 'list' type of dictionary values are unhashable.

What would be an efficient way to do this? (the number of dictionaries is relatively large).

Comment: In your original list of dictionaries, the third dictionary with key `deck` doesn't have `E`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes @JayPatel, it was a typo. They should be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `dict` to your unique `list` if it is not already contained within it (note that I'm assuming you meant for the third item to have an `'E'` in its `deck` list, otherwise it would not be a duplicate):

```
x = [
 {'101': ['A','B'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['D'],
  '104': [],
  '105': [],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']},
 {'101': ['A'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['B'],
  '104': ['D'],
  '105': ['E'],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']},
{'101': ['A','B'],
  '102': ['C'],
  '103': ['D'],
  '104': [],
  '105': [],
  'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}
]

unique_solutions = []
for d in x:
    if d not in unique_solutions:
        unique_solutions.append(d)
```

Or, you could create something like a `HashDict` class which implements hashes (in my example, using tuples, but this could be done in different ways) and create a `set`:

```
class HashDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self[k] = v

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple((k, tuple(v)) for k, v in self.items()))

hdx = [HashDict(d) for d in x]
unique_solutions = list(set(hdx))
```

Both examples result in

```
>>> print(unique_solutions)
[{'101': ['A', 'B'], '102': ['C'], '103': ['D'], '104': [], '105': [], 'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}, {'101': ['A'], '102': ['C'], '103': ['B'], '104': ['D'], '105': ['E'], 'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate through the dictionary value which is causing you error. You can append `dict` to the list if the value is not present already.

```
unique_solutions=[]
[unique_solutions.append(val) for val in lst if val not in unique_solutions]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(unique_solutions)
[{'101': ['A', 'B'], '102': ['C'], '103': ['D'], '104': [], '105': [], 'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}, {'101': ['A'], '102': ['C'], '103': ['B'], '104': ['D'], '105': ['E'], 'deck': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}]
```